# In Swift, is there a way to set a UIView's background to accomplish an overlay effect like Photoshop?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8

The designer used lots of overlay and multiply blend modes in his Photoshop design. Is there a simple way to set a UIView's background (or draw something to the CALayer) that will do the same thing as Photoshop's overlay (as well as multiply) filter? The goal is to blend the UIView's background with whatever appears behind it. This ideally would auto update if I animate the UIView's position as well.